# What is the data type for MySQL if something like 15h2 or 15'2 or 15,2 needs to be used?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Currently I have this as my code
t.float    "height",         limit: 24

I want to replace t.float to accept something like  15h2 or 15'2 or 15,2. Which is the best data type to be used instead of t.float.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You can use char or varchar, either will work. And note that you'll have to sanitize the input to insert it into database if you have special characters in it. If you're using any framework then I believe the framework will take care of sanitizing the input.

**Cons:** It might hurt performance.

Another way is to convert your float value into varchar and then save it as varchar data type.

Comment: does this apply to SQL db  also?

Comment: @Krishna This should apply to all relational databases such as MySQL, MSSQL etc.